# How to merge different images in one

Tags: android, android-image

I'm developing an Android application I have to implement a function that must  "merge" two images, but following certain rules.

The main image is a representation of a car where which each part (like hood, windshield) are colored differently, I have do this to map the car.

The other images represent each part of the main images, such as hood, windshield So what that I what to do is "simple" I need to overlap / merge each single part of the car with the main image.

Keep in mind that the images of each part are scaled 1: 1 compared to the main image.

The main image is mapped colors, so each to each part can be associated with a color.

The only question is how to "merge" different images with the main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) to build up the image. You can create a bitmap, then create a Canvas to be able to draw on it using `drawBitmap()`. First load up the base image and draw it to the canvas, then you are able to to the same for the other parts and position them as you like.